# Can the "New tags" section of the "tools" page only show tags that still have questions?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, moderator-tools

Look at the tools page for the [past 30 days](https://english.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=stats&daterange=last30days) shows these tags at the bottom:

[image]

Nearly all of the questions with those tags have been retagged so as to avoid the useless tags such as `words` or `usage`. I would find it helpful if the tag would stop showing up here once they were removed from the questions — I keep clicking on them thinking that something needs to get retagged.

Comment: Er, to introduce more of the problem to MSO: The `words` and `usage` tags are notorious at EL&U but still gather questions pretty frequently. We tend to swap them out as we find them but they gather too rapidly for the system to autoclean them.

Comment: If there are specific words that you want to ban as tags, you can ask a developer to ban them. Post the request on [meta.english.se], and a dev will to it if there's general agreement.

Comment: I remarked the same with the regular tag list on the new crypto stackexchange (still in private beta), where most tags are new and still a bit volatile. Either remove the empty tags from the list, or show them as `×0` or such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was mainly an issue around caching.

We already nuke all tags from the tag table if they have the count of 0. This happens **daily**.

However, there was an edge case that sometimes caused tag counts to go out-of-sync. Additionally, the query that checked for the list of new tags was not excluding tags with the count of 0.

---

Fixed now. You can safely remove the wacky tags and have them disappear from the list right away.

Answer (score 1):

I remarked the same on the cryptography site, when it was still in private beta, and users were creating and changing tags often (without any reputation limit).

I wish the list would somehow distinguish empty tags from one-question tags (tags with more than one question are already marked by showing the number).

Maybe it could show a `×1` for those who have only one question, and/or `×0` for those who have no question at all?

Answer (score 0):

New tags are also those tags that users add to questions, but that are then removed from another user.

I think it makes sense to know which tags are new, even in the case they are not used anymore. Seeing those tags allows you to request they are merged with existing tags, and made synonyms of the existing tags. If they were not reported in that page, you could not notice a user created those tags that have been removed from any questions.
You could also suggest those tags as synonym of existing tags, if you have enough score for the existing ones; they require four users that up-vote your suggested synonyms.